# How do I troubleshoot some unexpected error messages reported while booting Debian 10?

Tags: debian, boot, usb, dmesg

I upgraded my Debian from 9th version to 10th when Debian 10 was officially released. Since I upgraded to Debian 10, I am getting following messages while booting:

```
[   11.008027] pstore: Using compression: deflate
[   11.008597] pstore: crypto_comp_decompress failed, ret = -22!
[   11.008666] pstore: decompression failed: -22
[   11.008784] pstore: crypto_comp_decompress failed, ret = -22!
[   11.008845] pstore: decompression failed: -22
```

**Edit**: After clearing the log files from `/sys/fs/pstore` as suggested in comment and answer, `pstore:` messages are now gone. But messages (described below) from `usb 1-1.5` are still there which are taking too much time while booting.

Recently some messages regarding usb has also started flashing while booting:

```
[   91.875667] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 81 using ehci-pci
[   91.955706] usb 1-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   92.147658] usb 1-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   92.335657] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 82 using ehci-pci
[   92.415642] usb 1-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   92.603699] usb 1-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   92.711758] usb 1-1-port5: attempt power cycle
[   93.315668] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 83 using ehci-pci
[   93.731705] usb 1-1.5: device not accepting address 83, error -32
[   93.811713] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 84 using ehci-pci
[   94.227687] usb 1-1.5: device not accepting address 84, error -32
[   94.227912] usb 1-1-port5: unable to enumerate USB device
```

So, these `decompression failed` and `unable to enumerate USB device` messages are being reported many times during boot and hence it takes more time to reach the login screen. How do I troubleshoot and get rid of these messages so-that booting time can be saved?

By the way, the system looks working fine without any issue and *all USB ports of Laptop are also working fine* after startup.

[Here](https://bin.disroot.org/?daa5734bf586cada#Bn3iZ7s4aeh24CPenkfvntY28eCCtBnMtPn8ApoYyeES) is a full `dmesg` output. I am also attaching output of [lscpu](https://bin.disroot.org/?5bfed62bbba2834d#EjqURKkWnDM1FZeyTSzu7dQVZyeCyTGadvo8EdoXQYsC), [lspci](https://bin.disroot.org/?1d17d4a90864a3a1#76EJz2VRJ2x1eWU3jXYU1E3eYVp8ksXgNDmiXJfFCJhT) and [lsusb](https://bin.disroot.org/?289c3c412a1e804b#BkN9v4zyMFiF1J6m2vbLshn2NZKfuyKDrWGKoC5tXfZv).

Comment: What is the output of [hwinfo](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Hwinfo) run as root? My guess is that you could have some broken hardware (e.g. cheap USB keys or external USB disks may fail, and by personal experience are not very reliable). Did you have any encrypted partition?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch [this](https://bin.disroot.org/?f5ca45973ee0b598#J2JmMY87roa3R9SmCqqGCsUcp7VsD2ed9Dy3jPEm9h7Q) is an output of `hwinfo`

Comment: Consider contacting me by email to `basile@starynkevitch.net` with an URL mentioning your question. Don't comment your own question please, but do [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/566090/edit) it to improve it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch can we continue discussion on [chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat)?

Comment: Use also [smartctl](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/smartmontools/smartctl.8.en.html)

Comment: We did continue the discussion, but it was not convincing

Comment: (1) Try to [delete the log files in `/sys/fs/pstore`](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=143741#p708188).

Comment: @Freddy should I try `sudo rm -rf /sys/fs/pstore/*` ?

Comment: @Pandya you _never_ "try" with `-f` unless it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Freddy Thanks, yes, it has worked. See an update to the question.

Comment: You could try the command: devadm trigger - But i guess it won't be of any help. See my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages from `pstore` decompression are solved as per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/571316/66803).

I have just also figured out what cause errors relating to USB Device.

It was laptop's webcam which is not connected properly. I have confirmed it by `watch`ing the output of `lsusb`. Actually I found while testing webcam using Cheese that if I moves lid up and down, Cheese started to show "no device found". (This problem persist upon full opened position of lid). So, I have monitored the connection using `watch lsusb` that highlighted hardware fluctuates:

[image]

I was not aware about `-t` feature of `lsusb` which shows port-wise information. While restarting, I noted down the USB port that reports the error:

```
usb 3-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
usb 3-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 3-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 3-1-port5: attempt power cycle
usb 3-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
usb 3-1.5: device not accepting address 10, error -71
usb 3-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
usb 3-1.5: device not accepting address 11, error -71
usb 3-1-port5: unable to enumerate USB device
```

(In the question it is usb 1-1-5 but port may changes I think)

And figured out using `lsusb -t`:

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 59, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 59, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 7, If 3, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 7, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 8: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtsx_usb, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 480M
```

Here Port 5 shows **`Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo`** which [as per laptop manufacturer](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-in/sln298412/a-guide-to-webcams-on-dell-notebook-and-desktop-pcs-with-ubuntu-operating-systems?lang=en) driver/tools used to run webcam.

So, it is the problem of USB connection with webcam. Self-answering the question so that other which face similar problem may find it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Remove some files with

```
sudo rm /sys/fs/pstore/dmesg-efi-*.enc.z
```

This has been reported before. See e.g.
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=902966;msg=10
. Others simply mention `sudo rm /sys/fs/pstore/*`, I am not certain it is needed.

At any rate, it seems that, if your system is working fine, you may get rid of the information in pstore.
More about the *persistent store* `pstore`:

1. [https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/PstoreAndACPIERST](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/linux/PstoreAndACPIERST).
   Pstore is a kernel feature that dates to 2011. It provides a generic interface to storage that persists across reboots and gets used to save kernel messages during a crash, as covered in LWN's [Persistent storage for a kernel's "dying breath"](https://lwn.net/Articles/434821/) and [the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/pstore). Your kernel very likely has pstore built in and your Linux probably mounts the pstore filesystem at /sys/fs/pstore.
2. https://lwn.net/Articles/421297/
3. [pstore: new filesystem interface to platform persistent storage](https://lwn.net/Articles/421297/)
   Email between Tony Luck and Linus Torvalds.

Comment: Right. Messages from `pstore` while booting are gone now, see the revised question.

Answer (score -2):

This happens from time to time. My mouse does this sometimes. Pull and plug the device. It will work then, again. Windows does this, too. People there just never look into the eventmngr. The mouse just doesn't work or whatever hardware. ;)

You can't prevent it. It's the electronics, not the software!

Comment: How about all the smartasses waiting with downvoting, till someone came it with a solution. I just had that error again, yesterday. Pull & Plug. Everything good. I don't make or advocate the error. I'm just telling how it is and will be. I asked this question long before the OP. You are counter productive and childish......