# Can I disable particular usb port or device from loading while booting Linux?

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, usb

As I have explained in [this Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/566090/66803) and [Anaswer post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584915/66803), there is a problem with loading Webcam, which is connected through internal USB port and hence I am thinking to disable its loading while booting Linux.

```
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.5/product
Integrated_Webcam_HD
```

Here are some **`/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.5/power/`** configuration of the mentioned device, which may be useful for investigation:

```
$ for file in /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.5/power/*;do echo "$(basename $file) :" | tr -d '\n'; cat $file; done
active_duration :3404
async :enabled
autosuspend :2
autosuspend_delay_ms :2000
connected_duration :1541108
control :auto
level :auto
persist :1
runtime_active_kids :0
runtime_active_time :3080
runtime_enabled :enabled
runtime_status :suspended
runtime_suspended_time :1537788
runtime_usage :0
```

I've tried setting `0` to `runtime_suspended_time` which didn't work and setting `disabled` to `level` throws an "invalid argument" error probably because the kernel version compatibility?

Here is my system and kernel information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.132-1 (2020-07-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is there anyway to disable this usb device/port from loading while booting the OS?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the drivers for this usb to be loaded

```
echo '1-1.5' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

And whenever needed you can load manually

```
echo '1-1.5' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
```

---

For power off following method should work:

need to set `autosuspend_delay_ms` to `0`

(while keeping `control` as `auto`)

```
echo '0' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.5/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
```

This file contains an integer value, which is the number of milliseconds the device should remain idle before the kernel will autosuspend it (the idle-delay time). The default is 2000.
0 means to autosuspend as soon as the device becomes idle.
Negative values mean never to autosuspend. You can write a number to the file to change the autosuspend idle-delay time.